# Codeigniter Caching Problem. Cached data not working on website

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I have a problem with Codeigniter caching.

I'm attempting to cache data from my database and create a cache file in cache folder, but when refreshing my page it doesn't render the chached version, but after a second of refreshing it renders the cached version correctly.

What is the problem here?

```
if(!$this->data["etkinlikler"] = $this->cache->file->get(md5("etkinlikler")))
{
    $etkinlikCache = $this->site_model->etkinlikler(4);
    $this->cache->file->save(md5("etkinlikler"), $etkinlikCache, 300);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do not include code as images. Edit your post, add your code.

Comment: Where and how are you loading the cache driver?  Where is the code which outputs something to your browser?

Comment: I’m loading the driver top of these codes

Comment: $this->load->driver(‘cache’, array(‘adapter’ => ‘file’));